# Includes function returns apparently wrong false

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to show/hide elements using checkboxes to filter them by a client id.

I put the checked values into an array, then go trough each element to verify if them "data-client" value is in the filters array but i always get false, even when the `console.log` shows that it would return true.

i've made a codepen to do some tests: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RvQvRj?editors=1111#anon-login

Hope you can help me.

```
<div data-client="15"><h3>Pizza Client</h3></div>

<label class="filter-list__item" for="pizza">
  <span>Pizza</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="15" id="pizza">
</label>
```

```
let activeFilters = [];

$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  $checkbox = $(this);
  if($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    activeFilters.push($checkbox.val());
  } else {
    var index = activeFilters.indexOf($checkbox.val());
    if (index > -1) {
      activeFilters.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  updateProjects(activeFilters);
});

const projects = $('div[data-client]');
let updateProjects = function(activeFilters) {
  if(activeFilters.length == 0) {
    $.each(projects, function(i, e) {
      $(this).fadeIn("fast");
    });
    return;
  }

  $.each(projects, function(i, e) {
    let $actualProject = $(this);
    console.log( activeFilters.includes($actualProject.data('client')) );
    console.log($actualProject.data('client') + ' , filters: ' + activeFilters);

    if( activeFilters.includes($actualProject.data('client')) ) {
      $actualProject.fadeIn("fast");
    } else {
      $actualProject.fadeOut("fast");
    }
  });
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the return value of [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) (a *string*) into `activeFilters()`.

That wouldn't be a problem if `.data()` would also return a string, but...

jQuerys [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method tries everything to convert the string value of the `data-*` attribute to a *JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A string is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change its representation (for example, the string "100" is converted to the number 100, but "1E02" and "100.000" are left as strings because their numeric value of 100 serializes to "100")* ([Source](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)).

Either convert the value of the filter checkboxes into numbers

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this),
      value = parseInt($checkbox.val(), 10);

  if($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    activeFilters.push(value);
  } else {
    var index = activeFilters.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      activeFilters.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  updateProjects(activeFilters);
});
```

or convert the return value of the `.data('client')` call to a string before passing it to `.includes()`

```
$.each(projects, function(i, e) {
  let $actualProject = $(this);

  if( activeFilters.includes($actualProject.data('client').toString()) ) {
    $actualProject.fadeIn("fast");
  } else {
    $actualProject.fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

or use `.attr('data-client')`

```
$.each(projects, function(i, e) {
  let $actualProject = $(this);

  if( activeFilters.includes($actualProject.attr('data-client')) ) {
    $actualProject.fadeIn("fast");
  } else {
    $actualProject.fadeOut("fast");
  }
});
```

Example

```js
let activeFilters = [];

$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this),
      value = parseInt($checkbox.val());
      
  if($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    activeFilters.push(value);
  } else {
    var index = activeFilters.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      activeFilters.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  updateProjects(activeFilters);
});

const projects = $('div[data-client]');
let updateProjects = function(activeFilters) {
  if(activeFilters.length == 0) {
    $.each(projects, function(i, e) {
      $(this).fadeIn("fast");
    });
    return;
  }

  $.each(projects, function(i, e) {
    let $actualProject = $(this);

    if( activeFilters.includes($actualProject.data('client')) ) {
      $actualProject.fadeIn("fast");
    } else {
      $actualProject.fadeOut("fast");
    }
  });
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="filter-list__item" for="pizza">
  <span>Pizza</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="15" id="pizza">
</label>

<div data-client="15" data-name="Pizza"><h3>Pizza Client</h3></div>
<div data-client="14" data-name="Pizza"><h3>Pasta Client</h3></div>
```